# How to convert PSD file to responsive HTML file?

Tags: css, html

I need to display a psd file that contain several image into my website.
My web site is responsive.
In this case when i display images inside web page : I should set position of images to **absolute** 
When I get preview in mobile device position of images Shakes.

How can i export this psd file to html or svg file that position of images is fixed.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <img src="~/Images/package.png" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="~/Images/makesh.png" />
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: It is down  to html and css and has nothing to do with the PSD export

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `max-width` of your image container

```css
.image_container{ text-align: center;}
.image_container img{ max-width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="image_container">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuXLO.png" alt="gas-pipe">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr6u0.png" alt="gas-pipe">
</div>
```